# How to resolve this error in OpenErp?

Tags: odoo

I have been trying the following code in openerp and I had been getting this error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: name - name]

In my py file, i had inherited one module

```
class hr_expense_expense(osv.osv):
_name = "hr.expense.expense"
_inherit = "hr.expense.expense"
_inherits = {'hr.employee':'first_approver'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't give details, but I'm pretty sure the `_inherits` line should be removed. You probably made a confusion and actually want to add `Many2one`  relation.